# SSJS to save data into a data extension

Tags: marketing-cloud, ssjs

I am really new to SSJS but what I am trying to achieve is to pass some parameters in the URL from an email and capture them in the cloud page and then save that data into a DE using SSJS.

At the moment I have written the following:

```
%%[var @SubscriberKey,@email,@date
SET @SubscriberKey=RequestParameter('SubscriberKey')
SET @email=RequestParameter('email')
SET @date = NOW()]%%

<script runat="server">
Platform.Load("Core", "1.1.1");
var request = {}
var SubscriberKey = Variable.GetValue("@SubscriberKey");
var email = Variable.GetValue("@email");
var date = Variable.GetValue("@date");    
Write(SubscriberKey);
Write(email);
Write(date);
var SSJSentries = DataExtension.Init("SSJS entries");


  var row = {};
              row.EmailAddress = request.email;
              row.SubscriberKey = request.SubscriberKey;
              row.date = request.date;
             {
                Write("<br><br>DE row: " + Stringify(row));
              }
              try {
                // attempt to add a row
                SetVar("rowAddResults", SSJSentries.Rows.Add(row));
                 }

 catch (e) {
  Write("<br>Exception: " + e);
}

</script>
```

When I redirect to the cloud page from the email I get the following message:

My Subscriber Key Value  XXXXXXXXXX@yahoo.com   9/26/2019 5:04:50 AM
DE row: {"EmailAddress":null,"SubscriberKey":null,"date":null}
Exception: Object expected: SetVar

I can pass the params OK after the GetVariable but I don't know how to write to request the values & insert them in the Data Extension.

What did I miss?

Giulietta

Comment: Hi Giulietta, is there any reason why you need to use SSJS for this task? Adding rows to a DE cam also be done in AMPScript, and would make your code much simpler.

Comment: You're missing the SetVar function.  There's a fully functional SSJS version of this in my gist: https://gist.github.com/wvpv/19777e1167d6ac91e2e8

Comment: Here's a working demo: https://pub.s7.exacttarget.com/yo3hzpktgmu?qs=7145718410d87e2af4e5001112e1de43e2e457b69041ac21&mid=7203368

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, as Cameron Robert stated, you can easily do this via [UpsertData](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/upsertdata.htm) or [InsertData](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/insertdata.htm), etc. inside AMPscript.

Now, the issue in your current code is that you created a `request` object, but never filled anything in it, so when you try to fill in the `row` object via `request.email` you are pulling nothing as there is nothing inside it.

I would change it to be:

```
var row = {};
          row.EmailAddress = email;
          row.SubscriberKey = SubscriberKey;
          row.date = date;
```

As the `email`, `SubscriberKey` and `date` vars are already defined above. There is no need to push them into another object first (`request`).  From there it should function as expected.

As for AMPscript, you could literally remove all the javascript and replace it with a single function:

```
%%[
var @SubscriberKey,@email,@date
SET @SubscriberKey=RequestParameter('SubscriberKey')
SET @email=RequestParameter('email')
SET @date = NOW()
UpsertData('SSJS entries', 1, 'SubscriberKey', @SubscriberKey,'Email', @email, 'date', @date)
]%%
```

Comment: Hiya, thanks so much! I managed to change the Row but it still doesn't inject. Message I get is: <br>Exception: Object expected: SetVar.   I am out of my comfort zone with SSJS so this was a little self training exercise but i got stuck along the way. I know i could use amp script but i wanted to get a bit of hands on exercises with small SSJS exercises

Comment: sorry missed that, need to change it to `Variable.SetValue()` not `SetVar()` as that is not a predefined function in SFMC SSJS.